# angular masonry directive with serverside data

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How would I apply masonry grid with an angular directive where the element is created on server side and angular gets that via ajax. When it loads should check for directive and than simply apply the masonries jQuery

**from Masonry example**

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

what I try

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('masonry', function($parse) {
      return{
        restrict: "E",       
        compile: function (element, attrs) {

                element.masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.masonry-brick',
                    columnWidth: 70
                });


        }
      } 
    });
```

server side generated markup

```
<masonry>
  <div class="masonry-brick">
     <a href="#"><img src="/path/to/image" /></a>
  </div>
</masonry>
```

The point is that my masonry directive markup is generated by another directive which looks as it follows

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('SlugCtrl', function ($scope, WpApi, $compile, $filter, ngProgressLite, $timeout) {

    // the Content to be rendered.
   $scope.maincontent = [];
   //loading animate starts
   ngProgressLite.start();
   loadRemoteData();



   // load remote data from the server.
   function loadRemoteData() {
   // The WpApiService returns a promise.
        WpApi.getContents()
        .then(
            function( post ) {       
                applyRemoteData( post );       
            });    
    }

     // apply the remote data to the local scope.
    function applyRemoteData( newContents ) {   

        $scope.maincontent  = $compile( newContents[0].content )($scope);  

        //$scope.maincontent  = $compile( newContents[0].content )($scope);  
        //console.log($scope.maincontent); 

    }

  //loading animate ends
  ngProgressLite.done();        

}).directive('maincontent', function() {

    return {
            restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    maincontent: '=maincontent'
                },

                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                 
                  scope.$watch('maincontent', function(val) {
                        if(!val) { return; }
                        element.append( val  );                                      
                    });                              
                  }
                };
})
```

Thena I was trying the following on second directive which fires on masonry but the layers they won't be rendered in popper way and on resize screen skips out

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('masonry', function($parse) {
      return{
        restrict: "E",       
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var selector = element.parent('.gallery');

            if(selector){
                selector.masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.masonry-brick',
                    columnWidth: 70
                });
                console.log(selector);
            } else {
                alert();
            }

        }
      } 
    });
```

[image]

the problem seems to be related to wrong calculation on parent container

checking the dom I get `style="position: relative; height: 22233px;"` where height is quite big

Comment: doesn't the second codeblock work? what is the error?

Comment: second code block fires on masonry, the images they will show up as the uploaded example shows. On screen resize the directive does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Add a `$scope.$digest()` below the `$compile` in `applyRemoteData`:

```
function applyRemoteData( newContents ) {   

    $scope.maincontent  = $compile( newContents[0].content )($scope);  
    $scope.$digest()
    //$scope.maincontent  = $compile( newContents[0].content )($scope);  
    //console.log($scope.maincontent); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedsback. The proposed produces digets error.